# Blazor WASM redirect to page after login

Tags: blazor-webassembly

In my Blazor wasm app I have a default landing page for unauthorized access.
I would like to redirect to another page after a successful login.

Have been looking at the RedirectToLogin.razor page. Adding /Holidays after the uri but it's not working.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)}");
}
```

Have also tried this. It kind of works but the page are loaded twice because blazor has not finished the login process.

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="@RedirectToHolidayViewer" />

@code{
[Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }

private void RedirectToHolidayViewer()
{
    // this code will be hit twice 
    state.ReturnUrl = "/Holidays";
}
```

}

Comment: 2022-01-02 With Blazor hosted PWA CORE-6  I am seeking a working solution that you have questioned, above.  Any other answers?  ... Thanks John-

Comment: No this is still on my to-do list

Comment: ...I got something to work today.  I will type up a response for you to consider...thanks.